# How to plot two or more functions inside a box (SphericalPlot3D) in Manipulate?

Tags: graphics

I tried to graph the functions spA and spB inside the same box, but I can't get it. Any idea how to do it?

```
fs[theta_, phi_] := (1/(4*Pi))^(1/2)
fpx[theta_, phi_] := (3/(4*Pi))^(1/2)*Sin[theta]*Cos[phi]
fpz[theta_, phi_] := (3/(4*Pi))^(1/2)*Cos[theta]
fpy[theta_, phi_] := (3/(4*Pi))^(1/2)*Sin[theta]*Sin[phi]
spA[theta_, phi_] := (1/Sqrt[2]*fs[theta, phi] + 1/Sqrt[2]*fpx[theta, phi])^2
spB[theta_, phi_] := (1/Sqrt[2]*fs[theta, phi] - 1/Sqrt[2]*fpx[theta, phi])^2

fsp[Orbital_] := 
 SphericalPlot3D[Orbital[theta, phi], {theta, 0, Pi}, {phi, 0, 2*Pi},
  PlotRange -> All, 
  PlotStyle -> {{Pink, Directive[Opacity[0.5]]}, {Pink, 
     Directive[Opacity[0.5]]}}, PlotTheme -> "Scientific",
  AxesLabel -> {Style[x, Medium], Style[y, Medium], Style[z, Medium]},
   AxesStyle -> GrayLevel[0.3],
  Mesh -> 50, MeshStyle -> Opacity[0.2], ImageSize -> Small]

Manipulate[
 Switch[Orbital,
  s, fsp[fs],
  sp, Row[fsp /@ {spA, spB, {spA, spB}}]
  ],
 {{Orbital, sp}, {s -> "s", sp -> "sp"}, ControlType -> PopupMenu}]
```

[image]

Comment: Use [`Show`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Show.html?q=Show)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

fs[theta_, phi_] := (1/(4*Pi))^(1/2)
fpx[theta_, phi_] := (3/(4*Pi))^(1/2)*Sin[theta]*Cos[phi]
fpz[theta_, phi_] := (3/(4*Pi))^(1/2)*Cos[theta]
fpy[theta_, phi_] := (3/(4*Pi))^(1/2)*Sin[theta]*Sin[phi]
spA[theta_, phi_] := (1/Sqrt[2]*fs[theta, phi] + 1/Sqrt[2]*fpx[theta, phi])^2
spB[theta_, phi_] := (1/Sqrt[2]*fs[theta, phi] - 1/Sqrt[2]*fpx[theta, phi])^2
```

You tried to evaluate `{spA, spB}[theta, phi]`; instead use

```
fsp[Orbital_] := SphericalPlot3D[
  Evaluate[#[theta, phi] & /@
    Flatten[{Orbital}]],
  {theta, 0, Pi}, {phi, 0, 2*Pi},
  PlotRange -> All,
  PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.5, Pink],
  PlotTheme -> "Scientific",
  AxesLabel -> (Style[#, Medium] & /@ {x, y, z}),
  AxesStyle -> GrayLevel[0.3],
  Mesh -> 50,
  MeshStyle -> Opacity[0.2],
  ImageSize -> Small]

Manipulate[
 Switch[Orbital,
  s, fsp[fs],
  sp, Row[fsp /@ {spA, spB, {spA, spB}}]], {{Orbital, sp}, 
   {s -> "s", sp -> "sp"},
  ControlType -> PopupMenu},
 SynchronousUpdating -> False,
 TrackedSymbols :> Orbital]
```

[image]

Comment: Wow! I would never have thought of something like this. Thank you!

Comment: There are multiple ways to handle the different types of input. You could just supplement your definition with a definition to handle lists, e.g., `fsp[Orbital_List] := Show[fsp /@ Orbital]`